# PermissiveModifyControl throws DirectoryOperationException in C# LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices

Using the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace to add/modify attributes on an Active Directory group.  Code:

```
public void UpdateProperties(Dictionary<string, string> Properties) {

    List<DirectoryAttributeModification> directoryAttributeModifications;

    //  ... Code to convert Properties dictionary to directoryAttributeModifications
    //  There is one 'Add' modification, to set the 'description' of the group

    ModifyRequest modifyRequest = new ModifyRequest(groupDistinguishedName, directoryAttributeModifications.ToArray());
    modifyRequest.Controls.Add(new PermissiveModifyControl());
    ModifyResponse response = connection.SendRequest(modifyRequest) as ModifyResponse;
```

The `PermissiveModifyControl` is intended to keep the code from failing if the description already exists.  The only information on PermissiveModifyControl I've found is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx

which states:

> An LDAP modify request will normally fail if it attempts to add an attribute that already exists or if it attempts to delete an attribute that does not exist.  With `PermissiveModifyControl` the modify operation succeeds without throwing a `DirectoryOperationException` error.

However, when the above code gets to the `SendRequest()`, it throws a `DirectoryOperationException`:  "The attribute exists or the value has been assigned."

What I'm trying to avoid is having to query every property in the collection being passed; if it exists, create a `Replace` `DirectoryAttributeModification`; if it doesn't, create an `Add` instead.  From what I can glean, `PermissiveModifyControl` is supposed to do just that.

Can anyone shed some light on why `PermissiveModifyControl` still throws a `DirectoryOperationException`, and how to properly use it?

Thanks in advance!
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more experimenting, I've found that the documentation is misleading... you don't want to add an attribute, you want to replace it (`DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace`).  If the attribute exists, it will of course replace it.  If the attribute does not exist, it will create it.

The rest of my code is correct.